# How to control CMT injection from clients?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

Let's say I have an EJB.

```
@Stateless
public class PersistenceService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="dependent")
    private transient EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Is there any way to control the `unitName` value from the clients?

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/persistence")
public class PersistenceResource {

    //"some"
    @Inject
    private transient PersistenceService somePU;

    //"other"
    @Inject
    private transient PersistenceService otherPU;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create 2 CDI [qualifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbck.html) for your PUs:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface SomePC {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface OtherPC {
}
```

2) Then expose your PUs as CDI beans

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class EntityManagerProducer {


@Produces
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "somePU")
@SomePC
private EntityManager em;

@Produces
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "otherPU")
@OtherPC
private EntityManager em;
}
```

3) Inject both EMs in your service:

```
@Stateless
public class PersistenceService {

    @Inject 
    @SomePC
    private emSome;

    @Inject 
    @OtherPC
    private emOther;

    public SeomthingUseful doSomething(Context myContext){
      getEntityManager(myContext);
      ... 
    }   

    private EntityManager getEntityManager(Context myContext){
      if(myContext == SOME_PU)
        return emSome;
      return emOther;
    }
}
```

4) From your client, you can pass the context which will be used to select the appropriate PU (you could also create a RequestScoped bean for this purpose, in that case you don't have to use method param):

```
@RequestScoped
@Path("/persistence")
public class PersistenceResource {

   @Inject
   PersistenceService service;

   public void myMethod(){
      service.doSomething(myContext.SOME_PU);
   }


}
```

Context could be an enum with the different values you need (SOME_PU,OTHER_PU). As an alternative you can dynamically inject all EMs beans in your service by doing the following:

```
@Inject @Any Instance<EntityManager> emSource;
```

If you follow this path then everything is explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_obtaining_a_contextual_instance_by_programmatic_lookup)